# combine multiple rows into one rows with several column

Tags: mysql

hello im going to select and group by with field x but showing in one row with several column

```
SELECT * FROM `cityname` 
WHERE `city`='mashhad' 
group by `city`,`number` 
ORDER BY `city`
```

[image]

but i want  showing :

```
mashhad  935 915 937 901
```

Comment: Since you group by multiple column the result is of course the destinct values of those columns.

Comment: `SELECT group_concat(number)
FROM cityname
WHERE city = 'mashhad' 
group by number`

Comment: ok but any go one column i want to several column

Comment: mashhad       935,915,937,901 ==> one row with  two column  not accept

Comment: mashhad     935   915   937   901  ==> one row with 5 column is accept

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to all `number` of each `city`, and display all the number in separated columns, this will be a table pivot issue, try following query:

```
SELECT city, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN number = 935 THEN number ELSE NULL END) AS number_935, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN number = 915 THEN number ELSE NULL END) AS number_915, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN number = 937 THEN number ELSE NULL END) AS number_937, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN number = 901 THEN number ELSE NULL END) AS number_901 
FROM   cityname 
GROUP  BY city
```

## <kbd>Demo Here</kbd>